# Laravel cached routes file access, version 5.8

Tags: laravel

Okay so I want to access the cached file of routes in Laravel version 5.8 I know that there is somewhere Laravel saves this file but I am not sure where to look for it.
I already tried to check the these folders

```
Storage
Bootstrap
```

But I couldn't find the route cache file. All I find is cached views and cached services and packages but there is no cache file.

Really Thank you for your time :)

Comment: For what reason you want to see the route cache file?

Comment: To check how Laravel saves them, so I can use the same format in my Plugin

Comment: Even I have tried to find the file, But couldn't help. But you can view the routes list using `php artisan routes:list` command. But I'm unable to view the cached route file

Comment: that's the same case with me, Anyways thanks for your time @farooq

Comment: It's in `bootstrap/cache/routes.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in `bootstrap/cache/routes.php`.

The command `php artisan route:cache` or `php artisan optimize` (re)creates this file.

The command `php artisan route:clear` deletes this file.